# Why doesn't $ recognized in jQuery version 1.4.2?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is my code:

```js
$("span.cls").on("click", function(){
  $("#dialog").html("");
});
```

```css
span{
  border: 1px solid;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span class="cls">remove content below</span>

<div id="dialog"><p>something</p></div>
```

Is it possible to make code above working without changing in the same version of jQuery?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? What's happening instead of the div emptying out?

Comment: The error is `"Uncaught TypeError: $(...).on is not a function"` and has nothing to do with `$` not being recognized

Answer (score 3):

The jQuery [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function was added in jQuery version 1.7.

You should instead use the [`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) function, which was added in jQuery version 1.0. Note that, prior to version 1.4.3, you cannot specify eventData with this function.

For events other than click there are analogous functions, all of which exist from version 1.0 onward:

- [`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)
- [`.focus()`](http://api.jquery.com/focus/)
- [`.keypress()`](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/)
- and [more...](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/)

```js
$("span.cls").click(function(){
  $("#dialog").html("");
});
```

```css
span{
  border: 1px solid;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span class="cls">remove content below</span>

<div id="dialog"><p>something</p></div>
```

You can also choose to use the [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) generic event binder, which specifies event type as a string just like the `.on()` function. The `.live()` function was deprecated in favor of `.on()` in jQuery version 1.7, but since you are using an older version of jQuery it is still appropriate.

```js
$("span.cls").live("click", function(){
  $("#dialog").html("");
});
```

```css
span{
  border: 1px solid;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span class="cls">remove content below</span>

<div id="dialog"><p>something</p></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

`$` is recognized just fine. 
As the error says the problem is the `.on` method does not exist on that version.

Use `click` directly

```
$("span.cls").click(function(){
  $("#dialog").html("");
});
```

or even better (*should be a priority really*) upgrade your version (*as 1.4.2 was released in Feb 2010*).